# Eddystone + Google Beacon Platform

Tags: google-chrome, beacon, eddystone, google-nearby, google-beacon-platform

I am following the video from the google keynote (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3nYyApSiSLQ).  I also have the same beacon in the demo (iBKS 105) and managed to provision it to serve UID.  By using Google's Beacon Tools, I am able to detect and register the beacon in Google Beacon Dashboard and add in my attachments and URLs.

However, the moment I am done with the procedure, I am not able to see any nearby messages/notifications on my device.  The guy who presented the demo did it with ease and I am wondering where I went wrong.  What a I missing?  I have done pretty much what the guy told in his keynote.

I have tried serving for Eddystone URL and successfully broadcasted the URL.  I would really like to get the UID to work also.

Comment: new question:  can Eddystone UID be detected by iOS devices?

Comment: As far as I'm aware, the app-free solutions should only function with Eddystone URL and TLM. 

Conserning the URL - have you got the specifics covered: Google Chrome installed, physical web turned on, bluetooth and location on?

Comment: @Annina, got the specifics covered.  Managed to get it to work :)  My next research is actually the TLM part.  Do you know any good resources on how to go about?  I want to stay app free :)

Comment: Great that you got it working! Sorry got no tips for the TLM part. I've been mostly looking at the app-based stuff.

Comment: @Annina, yeah...i tried some stuff last night.  Seems that anything that you want to know about the beacon remotely, you must need an app

Comment: I think TLM is reported by bluetooth enabled devices nearby the beacon, and you can then access this data through the Google Proximity REST API

Answer (score 0):

I'm the guy in the video who did it with ease.

App-free solutions work with -UID, -EID, -TLM, -URL. On Android, you don't need an app to make your beacons useful.

If you do have an app, be sure to use Nearby Messages so that you get the most efficient possible scanning. (Also, no bluetooth permission required -- only location.)

The TLM frame will provide things like low battery alerts on the [dashboard](https://developers.google.com/beacons/dashboard). You don't need an app to see these; the battery level is reported to the service with any Nearby request (including for Nearby Notifications).

Choose an interleaving ratio of -UID to -TLM of about 10:1, depending on how much traffic you're expecting your beacon to get. (If it's in a busy place, and you only want updates once/wk, you can go much less frequently than 10:1 with your -TLM frame.)

There was a question about iOS. There's a Nearby Messages Cocoapod that you can use with your iOS app just [here](https://cocoapods.org/pods/NearbyMessages). There's currently no equivalent to Nearby Notifications on iOS.

HTH!